# What's the behaviour of Nikon Z cameras with dual card slots set to duplication, using different card sizes?

Tags: nikon, memory-card, backup

I'm wondering, what would happen if I ran out of space on one card while the other still had space, on Nikon Z cameras with dual card slots configured to duplicate?

For example, if one card is 64gb and the other 128gb, would the cameras continue writing to the 128gb and leave the 64gb alone or would they stop writing, requiring a setting change and or removal of the full card? I'm presuming they won't just start overwriting the 64gb! Would it matter which card is in which slot? For instance, the Z7II has a CFexpress and SDXC, so would I be able to get a 64GB CFexpress and 128GB SDXC and continue on the SDXC, though not duplicated?

Comment: It seems like the manual would explain this.

Comment: Hmm, I figured it out fortunately

Comment: I backup smaller jpegs to the second smaller card. The smaller file size generally means the smaller card does not fill up faster (or even as fast).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried this out with my older Nikon using 16GB and 64GB cards. The lower capacity is what the backup/duplication mode is limited to. Once this capacity is reached, removing the lower capacity card allows the larger one with remaining capacity to be utilized.